# Events from Firebase Analytics not showing up in Big Query

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have an trouble when linking Firebase Event to Big data.

1. In Firebase Analytics, I have many event .
2. I linked firebase with Big Query
3. But in Big Query, I can't see it.
4. How can I see it?

[image: View Images Here]

Comment: I think you just need to wait a day or something since you link bigquery

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en):

> Once an app is linked to BigQuery, a corresponding dataset is created in the associated BigQuery project upon the first daily export of events. Each day, raw event data for each linked app populates a new table in the associated dataset, and raw event data is streamed into an intraday BigQuery table in real-time. Data prior to linking to BigQuery is not available for import.

Comment: I see that. But how can i see event in big query

Comment: I found the explanation on the docs on how to link firebase analytics to bigquery. Not sure how but when I created the app the linking was de-activated